# ICMP packets can't be forwarded

Tags: networking, routes, forwarding

Machine A 10.167.27.10
Route on A is like：

```
0.0.0.0         10.167.27.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.167.28.20    10.167.27.11    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.167.27.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Machine B 10.167.27.11
Route on B is like：

```
default         10.167.27.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.167.27.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The ip_forward and accept_redirects is set to 1 on B.

And machine C is 10.167.28.20. I can ping C from B.
Since there is a route for C using B as a gateway on A, I thought if I ping C from A, I would get ICMP redirect message. But in fact I didn't get any reply.

I took tcpdump on eth0 on B, and saw ICMPs arrived. But why they were not forwarded?

**Update:**

On B I used Netfilter hook functions to output logs while the ICMP packets being processed. The log I added to the FORWARD hook point was printed and the routing result was correct. But the log at the POST ROUTING hook point was not printed. I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

Machine C know how to reply to A ? 
Machine  A know how to reach C (that's why you see the IMCP arrive at B) but if device C does not know how to reach A it will not respond to A (and the ping will fail).

Try to ping A from C. If it fail, add a route to machine A in device C.

Hope this help.

### Edit

This is your topology right ?

[image: Topology]

Since B is connected to all other devices it will know how to reach them. You juste has to enable forwarding on B and define the default gateway of A and C as B.

Comment: I tried to ping A from C. I find that the ICMP packets have arrived at A and A generated the replies then forwarded them to B which never returned to C...

Comment: In fact A and C can ping each other without B. I use B only to try IP forward thing...So When I ping A from C, the ICMP packets are not passing through B. I guess the problem may be on B.

Comment: Thank you for your further answer. I have enabled forwarding on B by setting ip_forward to 1 and there is a route on A and C defining B as the gateway. (Not default gateway though, I think it should work too.) I've updated my description. The packets have passed through the hook function at FORWARD but didn't reach POSTROUTING.

Comment: Can you share your NETFILTER configuration ?

Comment: Do you mean the rules in iptables? I've used 'iptables -F' to remove all the rules so it's empty.